# What is the proper way to compute graph diameter in GraphX

Tags: scala, graph-theory, spark-graphx

I'm implementing an algorithm on GraphX for which I need to also compute the diameter of some relatively small graphs.
The problem is that GraphX doesn't have any notion of undirected graphs, so when using the built-in method from ShortestPaths, it obsviously gets the shortets directed paths. This doesn't help much in computing a graph diameter (Longest Shorted undirected path between any pairs of nodes).

I thought of duplicating the the edges of my graph (instead of |E| I would have 2|E| edges) but I didn't feel it's the right way to do it. So, are there a better way to do it on GraphX notably?

Here is my code for a directed graph:

```
// computing the query diameter
def getDiameter(graph: Graph[String, Int]):Long = {
    // Get ids of vertices of the graph 
    val vIds = graph.vertices.collect.toList.map(_._1) 
    // Compute list of shortest paths for every vertex in the graph
    val shortestPaths  = lib.ShortestPaths.run(graph, vIds).vertices.collect
    // extract only the distance values from a list of tuples <VertexId, Map> where map contains <key, value>: <dst vertex, shortest directed distance>
    val values = shortestPaths.map(element => element._2).map(element => element.values)

    // diamter is the longest shortest undirected distance between any pair of nodes in te graph
    val diameter  = values.map(m => m.max).max
    diameter 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphX actually has no notion of direction it you don't tell it to use it.
If you look at the inner workings of the `ShortestPaths` library you'll see that it uses `Pregel` and the direction is default (`EdgeDirection.Either`). This means that for all triplets it will add both source & dest to the activeset.
However if you specify in the `sendMsg` function of `Pregel` to only keep the srcId in the active set (as is happening in the `ShortestPaths` lib) certain vertices (with only outgoing edges) will not be reevaluated.

Anyway a solution is to write your own Diameter object/library, maybe looking like this (heavily based on `ShortestPath`, so maybe there are even better solutions?)

```
object Diameter extends Serializable {
  type SPMap = Map[VertexId, Int]

  def makeMap(x: (VertexId, Int)*) = Map(x: _*)

  def incrementMap(spmap: SPMap): SPMap = spmap.map { case (v, d) => v -> (d + 1) }

  def addMaps(spmap1: SPMap, spmap2: SPMap): SPMap = {
    (spmap1.keySet ++ spmap2.keySet).map {
      k => k -> math.min(spmap1.getOrElse(k, Int.MaxValue), spmap2.getOrElse(k, Int.MaxValue))
    }(collection.breakOut) // more efficient alternative to [[collection.Traversable.toMap]]
  }

  // Removed landmarks, since all paths have to be taken in consideration
  def run[VD, ED: ClassTag](graph: Graph[VD, ED]): Int = {
    val spGraph = graph.mapVertices { (vid, _) => makeMap(vid -> 0)  }

    val initialMessage:SPMap = makeMap()

    def vertexProgram(id: VertexId, attr: SPMap, msg: SPMap): SPMap = {
      addMaps(attr, msg)
    }

    def sendMessage(edge: EdgeTriplet[SPMap, _]): Iterator[(VertexId, SPMap)] = {
      // added the concept of updating the dstMap based on the srcMap + 1
      val newSrcAttr = incrementMap(edge.dstAttr)
      val newDstAttr = incrementMap(edge.srcAttr)

      List(
       if (edge.srcAttr != addMaps(newSrcAttr, edge.srcAttr)) Some((edge.srcId, newSrcAttr)) else None,
       if (edge.dstAttr != addMaps(newDstAttr, edge.dstAttr)) Some((edge.dstId, newDstAttr)) else None
      ).flatten.toIterator
    }

    val pregel = Pregel(spGraph, initialMessage)(vertexProgram, sendMessage, addMaps)

    // each vertex will contain map with all shortest paths, so just get first
    pregel.vertices.first()._2.values.max
  }
}

val diameter = Diameter.run(graph)
```

Comment: I may add that `import scala.reflect.ClassTag` was needed in your proposition.